# Calculating and updating table with simple moving average of closing stock prices in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, finance

I could use some help (preferably a dummy's guide) to updating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SYMBOL` (
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adj_close` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `moving_average` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The moving_average column is empty now. All other columns are populated (for the time being, I'm ok with this being "static", it does not need to update as I add rows - though if this is easy to do, that would be great).  It is a 20-day moving average that I hope to calculate.

I have tried by performing the steps here to the best of my ability:

[How do I calculate a moving average using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878473/how-do-i-calculate-a-moving-average-using-mysql)

My query is this:

```
SELECT
     `close`,
     (
     SELECT
          AVG(`close`) AS moving_average
     FROM
          SYMBOL T2
     WHERE
          (
               SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
               FROM
                    SYMBOL T3
               WHERE
                    `day` BETWEEN T2.day AND T1.day
          ) BETWEEN 1 AND 20
     )
FROM
     SYMBOL T1
```

Have I modified the query correctly?  What needs to be done to write the results to the moving_average column?

When I run the above, nothing happens (it says its running, no errors, after letting it run for a long time I just stopped it).  The column moving_average still has NULL values.

I also looked at this answer:
[How to calculated multiple moving average in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059693/how-to-calculated-multiple-moving-average-in-mysql)

However, I'm unsure what I need to change to the reply for my table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The statement you posted has no update statement in it. Just a select. Naturally, this means nothing will get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Create an `update` query that updates every row in your table
2. Create a stored procedure that does the job

I personally prefer option 2:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure movingAvg()
begin
    declare mv double;
    declare t date;
    declare done int default false;
    declare cur_t cursor for
         select distinct day from symbol
         order by day;
    declare cur_mv cursor for
         select avg(close) from symbol
         where day between date_add(t, interval -19 day) and t;
         -- Here you define the interval of your MV.
         -- If you want a 20-day MV, then the interval is between t-19 and t
    declare continue handler for not found set done=true;

    open cur_t;
    loop_day: loop
        fetch cur_t into t;
        if not done then
            open cur_mv;
            fetch cur_mv into mv;
            close cur_mv;
            update SYMBOL
                set moving_average = mv
                where day=t;
        else
            leave loop_day;
        end if;
    end loop loop_day;
    close cur_t;
end;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank Barranka - I copied and pasted this and attempted to run it.  The result was "Query was empty".  I also did "show procedure status" and it was empty.  Should I modify this further?  Either way, thank you for the help!

Comment: @user1644609 you may need to check that i wrote everything right (i think i didn't screwed up, but there's always the chance i missed something), and then check your table... are the calculations correct?

Comment: I've tried to "debug" it, but honestly don't know whether its correct or not.  I've played around with it a little bit (and will continue to) but haven't been able to create the stored procedure, nor populate date into the moving_average column.  But thank you for putting me on a track.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barranka, I got it working after adding a semicolon at the end of the cur_mv declaration and changing the delimiter.  Really appreciate the help.  Can you recommend any online reading as I will be doing more calculations like this (more complicated) in the future?  Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1644609 Unfortunately I don't know about a site (other than this very site) where you can find help... The only thing I know for sure is that there's no better teacher than your own curiosity. Keep a copy of MySQL reference manual at hand, and take a look at it from time to time if you feel lost. Other than that, be curious and creative

Comment: @user1644609 by the way, thank you for finding the error (sorry about it, simply missed it); I've added the missing semicolon

Comment: Is there a way to change the table reference (SYMBOL) to a variable in the procedure, so that when calling the procedure the variable can be called?  ex. call movingAvg() Symbol; ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
update SYMBOLS
from (
   select a.day
        , avg(b.close) as moving_average
   from   SYMBOLS a
   cross join SYMBOLS b
   where b.day BETWEEN date_sub(a.day, INTERVAL 19 DAY) and a.day
      and a.moving_average is null
   group by a.day
   ) x
set moving_average=x.moving_average
where SYMBOLS.day=x.day
```

Sorry I don't use mysql myself, so I'm guessing on the date arithmetic syntax.  And I added a condition to only update rows where your `moving_average` is null.

**UPDATE:** Be sure you understand that this solution is based on a 365-day calendar.  Most stock market averages like "20-day" or "30-day" are based on a trading calendar which excludes weekends and holidays.  You would need to create a trading calendar table youself (a simple list of all trade dates).  If you want to do that, you might want to ask a new question to that effect.